# How do I get GNU screen not to start in my home directory in OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, gnu-screen

GNU Screen (`screen`) behaves differently on OS X 10.5 (Leopard) and 10.6 (Snow Leopard) compared to Linux (at least Ubuntu, Red Hat, and Gentoo) and OS X 10.4 (Tiger).  In 10.5 and 10.6, new screens (made with `screen` or `^A` `c`) always places me in my home directory `~`.  In Linux and OS X Tiger, new screens have a `pwd` of wherever the screen was created originally.

Made up examples to illustrate what I mean:

Tiger:

```
$ cd ~/foo
$ pwd
/Users/ben/foo
$ screen
$ pwd
/Users/ben/foo
$ screen # or ^A c
$ pwd
/Users/ben/foo
```

Leopard, Snow Leopard:

```
$ cd ~/foo
$ pwd
/Users/ben/foo
$ screen
$ pwd
/Users/ben
$ screen # or ^A c
$ pwd
/Users/ben
```

How do I get Leopard and Snow Leopard to behave like Tiger used to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better way to check what exactly is being run when you type `screen` would be to run `command -V screen`.  This will tell you whether it's running a binary (in which case the full path will be given) or a shell alias, function, etc.

Another thing to check is whether there's a `chdir` command in either your `~/.screenrc` or the system-wide `screenrc`.

Comment: Finally found out what was doing it.  I had `shell -$SHELL` in a section copied from a coworker.  The problem went away when it was removed.  It doesn't behave the same way as on Linux, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The `screen(1)` man page describes **the Screen `chdir` command**.

```
   chdir [directory]

   Change the current directory of screen to the specified directory or,
   if called without an argument, to your home  directory  (the  value  of  the
   environment  variable  $HOME).  All windows that are created by means of the
   "screen" command from within ".screenrc" or by means of "C-a : screen
   ..." or "C-a c" use this as their default directory.  Without a chdir command,
   this would be the directory from which screen was  invoked. …
```

My Screen configuration for a programming session includes the command

```
chdir "$HOME/Projects"
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to make sure that screen isn't an alias.

Type `alias` and look for `screen`.  Be warned that this list could be long. You may want to type `alias | grep screen` to separate the wheat from the chaff.

If `screen` turns out to be an alias for something like `cd ~ && screen` you can remove this using `unalias screen`.

Comment: Even better: use `type screen`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this web page here has your answer: http://code.google.com/p/silassewell/wiki/ScreenOSX